# How to make a heat map overlay (like Trulia crime) for google maps

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I'm interested in making a heat map based on a series of latitude longitude points. I've seen some examples that use the [heatmap api](http://www.heatmapapi.com/), but I'm looking to do something more like the way trulia is treating the [crime map](http://www.trulia.com/property/3011635690-131-145-Jackson-St-135-2B-Brooklyn-NY-11211). (scroll to the bottom to click on crime). Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This is not a heat map, but colored polygon overlays.  You need polygons linked to stats and then set the color based on some color ramp.

Comment: I see, it appears that each polygon corresponds to a block, and the color of each block is computed via some sort of algorithm. It seems like a pretty complicated implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if you could try using [Google Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home/) for this kind of heatmap presentation. More examples of it's usage, examples and the link to Fusion Tables API can be found here: [Fusion Tables Tour](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/public/tour/index.html#).

It is an experimental service from Google with which you can upload your own data in spreadsheets, CSV or KML format to Google and then visualize the given data with Tables API on map.

Answer (score 2):

There's a blog post on how they did it here: http://www.glenrobertson.co.nz/projects/2013/02/11/trulia-crime-map.html

Looks like they created their down custom map overlays using the US census data.